# Page Fault in Non-Paged Area BSOD

Tags: windows-10, bsod

While installing windows 10 even before the setup started this BSOD of page fault in non paged area pops up and I am unable to install it.The same problem with other Windows OS installation.

Comment: There is a [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area) explaining this issue. Since it is a memory issue, you could try the `memtest86+` program usually found on bootable Linux ISO's.

Comment: Thanks for posting to SuperUser!  The question is a bit unclear.  Please edit the question and title with the following details : What precise version of Windows 10 (if downloaded today, it's v1803) , are you booting from an install CD or USB stick versus running the setup.exe while logged into older Windows, by "other Windows OS" do you mean "older Windows OS", and most importantly , what's the precise error?

Comment: Thank you all but I have understood the problem and got it under control.The problem was damaged battery for the laptop ,when I removed the battery and ran the laptop using direct power source I was able to install it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all but I have understood the problem and got it under control.The problem was solved by updating the BIOS .

Answer (score -1):

Your "question" could really use a lot more details . What was the faulting module (ideally, the whole error)? What kind of hardware are you running? Has the computer ever worked, and what was the "other Windows OS" you tried installing? What else have you tried?

I'll take a guess at the problem, though.

Based on what you've said, I would guess you either have bad install media (either it was prepared incorrectly from the download, it was pirated, or both) or you have a hardware issue. If it's the install media, you could try downloading a Linux ISO, which is somewhat easier to self-prepare, and booting that; if it works, go take your bad media back to the store (or buy good media in the first place) and use that. If it doesn't work, hardware is the most likely issue.

Hardware could be any of a few problems, but the most likely is probably RAM. If you're overclocking either the CPU or the RAM, turn that back down to manufacturer-recommended speeds. If you can, run the `memtest` program (found on most OS install media, including Windows) - you can run it before you begin installation of the OS - and see if it detects any RAM errors. You could also try removing all but on RAM module at a time and seeing if that works (assuming your computer has multiple modules and they're removable). If it's not the RAM, next most likely would be either the CPU or the chipset (supporting hardware on the motherboard). That's generally harder to fix. If the CPU was manually installed, a slightly-incorrect installation (such as bending a single pin) could produce that problem.